# Is my modification of Newton's law of cooling legitimate?

Tags: calculus

I'm working on temperature prediction and therefore also cooling. I stumbled upon Newton's Law of Cooling (NLC) and I do like its simplicity, but I'm not so happy about the condition that the surrounding temperature must be constant.

Original formula I'm working with
$$T(t) =  (T_0 - T_A) * e^{^-kt} + T_A$$

$T_0$ is temperature at $t = 0$

$T_A$ is ambient temperature

$k$ is the inverse time constant

$t$ is time.

The problem I have with this formula is that it assumes instant cooling from $T_0$ and that $T_A$ is constant. The resultant cooling is something like below:

[Newton Cooling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYo9f.png)

Imagine an oven at 150$^oC$ with a sausage that is 70$^oC$. If the oven shuts off suddenly, the ambient temperature will start to drop. Therefore $T_A$ cannot be constant. Furthermore, $T(t)$ will not instantly drop when the oven drops, but will increase until $T_{oven} = T(t)$. So what if the formula was modified so that $T_A$ also is dependent on time?

Well that is exactly what I did. I played around a bit with the formula and ended up using the formula recursively, so that $T_A$ is also determined by NLC.

This gives me the formula:

$$T(t) =  (T_0 - ((T_{A0} - T_{AA}) * e^{^-k_At} + T_{AA})) * e^{^-kt} + (T_{A0} - T_{AA}) * e^{^-k_At} + T_{AA}$$

I know, bear with me, please.

In out sausage example, $T_{A0}$ is now the oven temperature, and $T_{AA}$ is the ambient temperature outside the oven. The neat thing about this is that it is possible with acceptable accuracy to assume that the outside temperature of $T_{AA}$ will not change with time as it is a large room. $k_A$ is the time inverse constant for the interaction between oven and outside ambient temperature.

Now the problem arises when we want to know what $k$ and $k_A$ is, as the formula now is much more complex. I've managed to sidestep this problem with assumptions and some iterative coding to estimate the $k$ and assuming that $k_A$ can be derived from $$\frac{dT}{dt}=-k_A (T_{A0}-T_{AA})$$ This is all beyond this question though.

**To conclude my question:**

The results are quite nice giving me a much more realistic cooling curve as seen below:

[Modified Cooling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIUiN.png)

Unfortunately, as you might have weaned from this question, I'm not math savvy and so I have no idea whether I've broken like a 100 fundamental rules of mathematics or not.

If the results are good, is this modification (gross infraction) acceptable?

Is there anything in the pure mathematics that says I cannot use this to predict/estimate cooling times of objects in given circumstances such as the oven example?

Comments, pointers, raging scolds and so on are all welcome

Cheers

Comment: This is very interesting. May I suggest you post at  physics.stackexchange.com ? It is really worth to be discussed.

Comment: Ah, good idea, i'll try that. Do you know if it is acceptable to copy paste a question from one forum to another ?

Comment: I think that there a mecanism for transfering but I do not know. What you could do, at least for the time being, is to delete this post and copy it to the other forum. May be, later, come back. I am extremely curious and interested? Cheers :-)

Comment: @Bernard. What do you think about this ? Cheers

Comment: Have a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48035/modification-of-newtons-law-of-cooling

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i'll keep the question here for now, to see if anyone is interested. After a while i'll try physics.stackexchange.com. Thank you

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I agree with you, this is a physics question. Now if some one is able to answer, why not?  I'm not, personally :-(

Comment: I asked the same question in physics.stackexchange.com. I think the answer is adequate, but its hard for me to asses with my limited knowledge. The link is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/583301/is-my-modification-of-newtons-law-of-cooling-an-infraction/583333#583333